Sections of a quotient vector bundle
Notation: If $E$ is a vector bundle, I denote $\Gamma(E)$ the module of sections of $E$.
Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a vector bundle and let $F\subseteq E$ be a sub-bundle.

Is it true that $\Gamma(E/F)\cong \Gamma(E)/\Gamma(F)$?

Clearly I'm identifying $\Gamma(F)$ with the submodule of $\Gamma(E)$ made of sections whom image is contained in $F$. This seems natural, but not totally trivial.
My attempt
Let $p:E\to E/F$ be the quotient map (with respect to the equivalence relation that defines the quotient vector bundle). We have the module homomorphism
$$\Gamma(p):\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E/F), \ \ \ \sigma\mapsto p\sigma. $$
The kernel of $\Gamma(p)$ is clearly $\Gamma(F)$. The tricky part is proving that $\Gamma(p)$ is surjective. Basically I need to prove that every sections of $E/F$ lifts to a section of $E$. Is this even true? Maybe there is some useful result in algebraic topology "lifting lemmas".

What's $M$? Any topological space? ...because if $M$ is nice enough (namely paracompact), then $E$ splits as a direct sum of $F$ and its orthogonal complement in some choice of metric, whence surjectivity is obvious.

@BenSteffan My bad. I'm working in the smooth category.

Since you're working in the smooth category, every vector bundle $E$ splits as $F \oplus F^\perp$ where $F \subseteq E$ is a subbundle and $F^\perp$ its orthogonal complement in some choice of bundle metric on $E$. Thus, without loss of generality, it suffices to consider the case that $p\colon F \oplus F' \to F$ is the canonical projection onto the first summand, and here the situation is clear: $p$ admits a section, namely the inclusion map $F \hookrightarrow F \oplus F'$, so $\Gamma(p)$ is surjective.
